# wordpress woocomec product to cant add some link or text under the product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im used WooCommrece plugin for a my wordpress website .I  have a some issue, Im try to display some link for products , example when I click the button or text website redirect another website , but its not display for me, 
l

```
 <a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html" class=&quot;button wc-backward&quot; href=&quot;<?php echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( '4736' ) ); ?>&quot;><?php _e( 'within local post', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I fixed my issue,

Im added following this code  to `content-product.php`

```
<button  style="background:#afb0b9; color:white;">
<a href="http://www.google.com" class=&quot;button wc-backward&quot;<?php echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( '1' ) ); ?>&quot;><?php _e( 'Within Delivery to US', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
</button>
```